# Sequential data fetching in Server Component to mutate same set of data (Next.js)

Tags: next.js, websocket, streaming, server-side-rendering, mutation

I am new to next.js (using v13 with App Router) and I am seeking advice on an issue I've been grappling with.

My goal is to **render data on a page, and progressively update it** as "better" data comes in (e.g., more recent data, data from more sources, etc.). Typically, there should be **2-3 updates** until the data has finished loading (e.g., on a hotel booking website, where options update progressively until the loading indicator turns off). I want to execute this **server-side as much as possible**.

When data needs to be updated, my API response (Django backend) includes a `"next"` entry with a url, e.g.:

```js
{ "meta": {..., "next": "https://api.example.com/path/to/next/request"}, 
  "data": ... }
```

The next.js doc is quite clear on [sequential data fetching](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching#sequential-data-fetching), but it does not show how to **update the same set of data**, only how to **display different blocks of data progressively**.

After trying different approaches, I implemented a solution that employs a **recursive component**, populating a `<Suspense>` boundary with the **current data** as `fallback`.

```js
import { Suspense } from 'react';

export default async function Stream() {
  return (
      <div className='m-auto h-screen w-1/2 p-3'>
        <h1>Welcome to the Stream page!</h1>
        <Results url={'http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/dummyData'} />
      </div>
  );
}

async function Results({ url }: { url?: string }) {
  const content = await fetch(url, {
    cache: 'no-store',
  }).then((res) => res.json());
  
  // if "next" url in response, insert in recursive function
  if (content.next) {
    return (
      <Suspense fallback={<ResultsDisplayer content={content} />}>
        <Results url={content.next} />
      </Suspense>
    );
  } else {
    return <ResultsDisplayer content={content} />;
  }
}

async function ResultsDisplayer({ content }) {
  const isLoading = Boolean(content.next);
  return (
    <>
      <p>Loading: {isLoading ? 'YES' : 'NOPE'}</p>
      <br />
      <p>Data:</p>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(content)}</pre>;
    </>
  );
}
```

[Illustration of recursive solution (GIF)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82osd.gif)

This solution seems to work, but **I am curious if there is a more conventional/straightforward  approach** to achieve **server-side data mutations triggered by chained hyperlinks**. I couldn't find any good examples or docs that covered this use case.

I've explored other options while researching the problem, but none of them was really fitting:

- **Client-side update** (e.g. with useSWR and useEffect), but wanted to avoid client-side fetching
- **Websocket**, but probably an overkill and looks like it can only be consumed client-side
- **ReadableStream**, as per the next.js doc on [route handlers](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers#streaming), but could not make it work (and again didn't seem consumable server-side)
- **[Server Actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions)**, using the [revalidateTag](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions), but it's still experimental, and I couldn't find an easy way to tell the client when to refresh.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? If so, how did you handle it? Are there features of next.js that I might have overlooked or misunderstood?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question. To rephrase I feel like you want to have only one HTTP request, send response data progressively, but have the client to update as data are incoming.

I think you need to use streams both ways, server and client.

First you need to respond with a `ReadableStream`. The code is a bit too complex to share here, you may want to read [this GitHub discussion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/15453#discussioncomment-6589193) about sending files with Route Handlers, it shows different syntaxes to achieve this goal.

Then, client-side, you can fetch this endpoint and consume the stream, using a similar API. The fetch `Response` body will be a `ReadableStream` with your data.

You can use the stream event handlers to update a state variable that will rerender your component. There are perhaps solutions with `<Supspense />` or incoming `use` hook but I don't think you need that, instead of using a promise client-side you can stick to event handlers.

One thing you need to figure is how to make each chunk of data "standalone" (= a complete string that you can call `JSON.stringify` upon), there are probably ways to send the chunk size along size the chunk (for instance send the size then the string then the size etc. until you send -1 to close the stream).

---

That's for the theory. In practice, an issue you may encounter is that in Route Handlers, you need to return a Response object, and then only Next.js will start triggering the HTTP response. While in an API Route/Express endpoint, you can call `res.send` anytime, and then feed the stream.

Basically this mean that I am not sure about the stream lifecycle: can you keep feeding the stream *after* you returned from the Route Handler function? Probably yes but it's worth a try.